# How to unpause a particular gameobject in unity?

Tags: unity

Say, I have a GUI Menu attached in a game scene. The game will be in pause state by default. I did it by setting "Time.timescale=0.0f"; I want my game to unpause only when Play button clicked. My question is how to access game scene from the script? And, what I to write on "OnClick" event? Your any suggestion will be highly appreciated. Regards

Answer (score 2):

"How to access game scene from the script?" If you want to load a game scene use [LoadLevel](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.LoadLevel.html) as mentioned. If you want to set the value of Time.timescale on a button click use [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.Button.html). However, I would suggest implementing a [fsm](http://unitygems.com/) to handle various game states.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure of what is your problem. But what I understand is that you start your game with Time.timescale at 0 and whant a specific game object to be "unpaused" (ie. not affected by the Time.timescale property).

As far as I know it's not possible for a specific game object to use a different TimeScale value.

I'd suggest to implement and use your own Timer system for pause and not use timescale anymore. The idea is that all your game object could use their own timers (updated by Time.time / Time.deltatime provided by Unity), then you'd be able to pause and unpause any game object you want, independantly from the rest of the game.

I hope it helps.